# What is alluded by 'Sei proprio un italiano di professione'?

Tags: grammar

Often I hear phrases like,

> Sei proprio un italiano.
>
> Sei proprio un italiano *doc*.
>
> Sei proprio un italiano vero.
>
> Sei proprio un italiano di professione.

and so on.

Do they have a positive or a negative connotation? And, be the first or the second case, what do they precisely mean?

Comment: This is *heavily* context-dependent.

Answer (score 10):

It means

> You are a stereotypical (or typical) Italian.

This can be said either implying pride or criticism, depending on which aspect of your interlocutor refers to within the context.

Answer (score 2):

The first and the last sentences have a negative connotation, which is based on any possible negative cliché related to being an Italian. The second and the third ones are positive, but still referring to some clichè.

EG: if you have an Italian friend who has a croissant and coffee for breakfast every morning, you could say to him, ehy "Tu sei un italiano  doc" (*You are really Italian*).

Comment: There are nuances for each version of the sentence bu none is intrinsically negative.

Comment: @Bruno, generally speaking I agree, except for the fourth expression of which I'm not able to think of a case when it can have a positive connotation, though.

Comment: @Bruno9779 correct, but the colloquial language can use even bad words to give a positive meaning to a phrase, eg: "you are a bad ass" in english or "Hai un gran culo in Italian" . Both really positive.

Answer (score 1):

**Sei proprio un italiano.**

Sounds offensive...

**Sei proprio un italiano doc.**

Sounds good

**Sei proprio un italiano vero.**

Sounds good

**Sei proprio un italiano di professione.**

Sounds offensive